# complex subsequences of divergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis

How does one prove that every bounded, yet divergent sequence of real numbers has 2 (separately, with different limits) convergent subsequences? Is this trivial because if all convergent subsequences had the same limit, the sequence would converge?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is incorrect. You say:

> If all convergent subsequences have the same limit, the sequence converges

Which is not true, as shown by the sequence

$$1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1,\dots$$

in which all convergent subsequences have the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

What is true is :

If $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge, then all subsequences of $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge and all the subsequences of $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge to the same limit.

The contrapositive of this statement is :

There exist a divergent subsequence of $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ OR there exist two subsequences of $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with two different limits.

Comment: thank you. Does the fact that the sequence is complex affect the argument?

Comment: @ak55 : No, it does not. The first statement in my post is true for complex sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Now mix the [Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) into [@jibounet's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/987165/148995).

Comment: That a bounded sequence must have a convergent subsequence, and that if all subsequences converged to the same limit, the sequence would converge?